# How to read ORB and SIFT descriptors?

Tags: opencv

I saved ORB and SIFT descriptors in xml.
I tried use `Mat descriptors = imread("descriptor.xml")`
but it didn't work.
it's blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say that you have stored the SIFT descriptor in `descriptor.xml`. Use the following code to assign the saved descriptor back to a `Mat` variable.

```
Mat sift_descriptor; 
FileStorage fs("descriptor.xml", FileStorage::READ);
fs["descriptor"] >> sift_descriptor;
fs.release();
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But ORB descriptors still blank. it didn't load success

Comment: @kjhgfdsa1021: Did you have a look at your `xml file`. May be, its empty so you are not getting anything. Please update the code about how are you trying to read for `ORB`

Comment: I was key wrong FileNode ,so descriptor is empty.Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to save and load `Mat`s that are not images with `cv::FileStorage`.